# How much is tax exemption if I retire in a foreign country like Taiwan?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, non-resident, tax-exemption

I heard that some time ago, there was like a US$70,000 tax exemption if I live in Hong Kong, and that first $70k income is not subject to US taxes.

However, let's say if I actually retire and live in Taiwan, is there such exemption as well?

That is, if I retire and don't work there but perhaps get US$1500 social security per month and plus $300 as interest and dividend per month, and if I sell some stocks and realize gain that is $20,000 that year, am I subject to any tax and what's the exemption limit?

Comment: @base64: but US citizen who moves to another country remains a citizen, and NOT an NRA. Also the dividend rate is 30% _or_ lesser treaty rate. OP: in addition to paying taxes if applicable, remember as US citizen you must every year _report_ foreign accounts to both FinCEN (FBAR aka form 114) _and_ IRS (form 8938, if above filing threshold); see https://www.irs.gov/businesses/comparison-of-form-8938-and-fbar-requirements . You do continue to get the standard deduction (which NRAs don't), and depending on your other income Social Security _may_ be exempt from US tax.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Agreed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The United States has "Tax Treaties" with quite a few foreign nations. The purpose of these treaties are to ensure citizens or residents of a country do not pay both US taxes and the taxes of their country of residence. It also outlines rules that prevents US citizens or residents from evading US taxes.

There is more information and a list of nations with these treaties at the [irs.gov website](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-states-income-tax-treaties-a-to-z). As base64 pointed out, neither Taiwan nor Hong Kong are on this list.

From [Cover & Rossiter](https://www.coverrossiter.com/news/2017/05/tax-implications-of-retiring-overseas-2/):

> **Tax Implications of Retiring Overseas**
> Leaving the United States does not exempt U.S. citizens from their U.S. tax obligations. While some retirees may not owe any U.S. income tax while living abroad, they must still file a return annually with the IRS. This would be the case even if all of their assets were moved to a foreign country. The bottom line is that you may still be taxed on income regardless of where it is earned.

In the case where a Tax Treaty does not exist, the Foreign Tax Credit system would be relevant *if* a given country taxes US Social Security and/or realized or unrealized investment income. This system, like the Tax Treaties, can compensate an individual when taxes are paid to both the US **and** the foreign country of residence.

From [irs.gov - Foreign Tax Credit](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-tax-credit):

> If you paid or accrued foreign taxes to a foreign country or U.S. possession and are subject to U.S. tax on the same income, you may be able to take either a credit or an itemized deduction for those taxes.

Comment: Additional coverage on at least some basics of Foreign Tax Credits is really needed to give full value to this answer.

Comment: Neither Taiwan nor Hong Kong are treaty jurisdictions.

Comment: Answer edited to include information on Foreign Tax Credits @Grade'Eh'Bacon and also base64's important note

Comment: The edits are good - per other comments looking further, it seems that agreements potentially allowing these benefits for residents of Hong Kong have been rescinded by the US government since 2019. Still relevant to the OP or for future similar use.

Comment: @base64 I think I know why, since 1997, Hong Kong is officially considered to be part of China

Comment: Income Tax Treaty of 1984 between United States and People's Republic of China **does not** cover Hong Kong and Taiwan. Tax Jurisdictions are seperate from other recognitions, similar how how Taiwan is called "Separate Customs Territory of Taiwan, Penghu, Kinmen, and Matsu" in World Trade Organization. The United States does not establish tax treaty to low tax / tax havens like Hong Kong and Singapore, because there is no Foreign Tax Credit needed to begin with.

Comment: @base64 good to know of all these rules and laws, and that, "I want to save more money for retirement in IRA or 401k" and "No, we won't let you. We control how you save money and how you retire and how you work for us."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion, which is now a little over $100k/year.

However, Social Security benefits would **not** qualify.

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion

> Not foreign earned income: Foreign earned income does not include the following amounts:
>
> - ...
> - Pension or annuity payments, including social security benefits

The same is true for the interest, dividends, capital gains, etc. you mention, as it is considered *unearned* income.

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-what-is-foreign-earned-income

Comment: While the info on the FEIE is helpful, an additional note on potential ability to claim Foreign Tax Credits on passive income is needed to provide additional context to the answer.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I've updated the answer to include the passive income sources OP mentions.

Comment: What I mean is - while FEIE is one method of reducing US taxes owed by an expatriate [and is the one inferred by the OP's question], claiming foreign tax credits is another possible method [and is the one more likely to suit the OP's needs, whether they were aware of them when asking the question or not].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I would encourage you to submit an answer.